# How to determine the coordinatesystem of a shapefile set with ShapefileDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, geospatial, shapefile, nettopologysuite

I have the following code to read a shapefile set (.dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx) with the `NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapefileDataReader`:

```
public FeatureCollection ReadShapeFile(string localShapeFile)
{
    var collection = new FeatureCollection();
    var factory = new GeometryFactory();
    using (var reader = new ShapefileDataReader(localShapeFile, factory))
    {
        var header = reader.DbaseHeader;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var f = new Feature {Geometry = reader.Geometry};

            var attrs = new AttributesTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < header.NumFields; i++)
            {
                attrs.AddAttribute(header.Fields[i].Name, reader.GetValue(i));
            }

            f.Attributes = attrs;

            collection.Add(f);
        }
    }
    return collection;
}
```

This works, but the geometry objects don't have a property to tell which reference system the coordinates are in.

How can I find out which coordinate system / reference system the shape file or individual shapes are in?

Answer (score 0):

The projection is not available in the .shp file, but in the .prj file, and can be loaded separately:

```
var projectionFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(localShapeFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(localShapeFile) + ".prj");
var projectionInfo = ProjectionInfo.Open(projectionFile);
```

Comment: where does ProjectionInfo come from?

Comment: It's from  `dotSpartial`

Answer (score 0):

From: [How to read Shapefile's prj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468307/how-to-read-shapefiles-prj-file)

```
var projectionFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(localShapeFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(localShapeFile) + ".prj");
var coordSystem = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(File.ReadAllText(projectionFile)) as CoordinateSystem;
```